# find all columns with character formated date values

Tags: r, sqlite, datetime

I have a R dataframe that I created from a sqlite database table.  This data has many date time columns that are now character columns.  I would like to mass convert them to date columns in the dataframe.

I can do it one column at time like this:

```
loan$Maturity <- as.Date(gsub(', 12:00:00 AM', '', loan$Maturity), "%m/%d/%y")
```

I can do a mass update for for all columns that are factors.  Every column that is a date value contains the

```
i <- sapply(loan, is.factor)
loan[i] <- lapply(loan[i], as.character)
```

How can I grab every column that contains the text ", 12:00:00 AM" and then change all fields using a function as.Date() to converts all character values to a date value.

Comment: So does a column match if it contains even a single instance of `, 12:00:00 AM`, or must every row contain this?

Comment: Why not use `lapply` on the entire data frame, and conditonally convert the columns you want?

Comment: Not every column has a match of the text or a row with a value, some are NA's

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.  Is the presence of a _single_ match in a column indication that this column should be treated as date?

Comment: Yes a single match means the column is a date column.  Sorry, I didnot comprehend your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution assumes (as @Tim was asking) that a single instance of `, 12:00:00 AM` in a column constitutes a conversion.

I supply two versions that do the check and conversion.  The first uses `vapply` to find which columns to convert, and then converts them in an `lapply`.  The second version does the check and conversion in a single `lapply`.

```
#create dummy data.frame
df <- data.frame(a=1, b='1/1/92, 12:00:00 AM')
#check which columns have ', 12:00:00 AM' in them
convertCols <- vapply(df, function(col) sum(grepl(', 12:00:00 AM', col)) > 0, logical(1))
#convert only columns that contained ', 12:00:00 AM' using your conversion function
df[convertCols] <- lapply(df[convertCols], function(dates) as.Date(gsub(', 12:00:00 AM', '', dates), "%m/%d/%y"))

#create dummy data.frame
df <- data.frame(a=1, b='1/1/92, 12:00:00 AM')
#done in single lapply
df[] <- lapply(df[], function(col) {
  if(sum(grepl(', 12:00:00 AM', col)) > 0) as.Date(gsub(', 12:00:00 AM', '', col), "%m/%d/%y") else col
})
```

If every element in the column must contain `, 12:00:00 AM` to constitute the conversion then the check would switch to `sum(grepl(', 12:00:00 AM', col)) == length(col)` as opposed to `sum(grepl(', 12:00:00 AM', col)) > 0`

Comment: This is what I was needing. I did not think about vapply and the use of logical.  Your help is appreciated.